# Is there a way to specify a column name as an argument?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Let's say I want to create a function that replicates a column of choice, for the sake of an example.

```
testdata <- data.frame(
  "diff1" = c(seq(1:10)),
  "diff2" = c(seq(21:30))
)

goal <- testdata %>%
  mutate(newdiff1 = diff1)
```

So I create a function

```
funtest <- function(dat,var,newvar){
  dat %>%
    mutate(newvar = var)
}
```

however,

```
test2 <- funtest(testdata,diff1,newdiff1)
```

would return an error:

```
 Error: object 'diff1' not found
```

This format works

```
nondesiredformat <- funtest(testdata,testdata$diff1,newdiff1)
```

but this will cause the new variable to be always called "newvar", instead of our third argument.

is there a way to change the function so the arguments in test2 may work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, we can use `{{}}` for doing the evaluation i.e. `!!` + `enquo` for unquoted variable names passed into function and for assignment, use the `:=` instead of `=`

```
funtest <- function(dat,var,newvar){
   dat %>%
     mutate({{newvar}} := {{var}})
        }
funtest(testdata, diff1, newdiff1)
#    diff1 diff2 newdiff1
#1      1     1        1
#2      2     2        2
#3      3     3        3
#4      4     4        4
#5      5     5        5
#6      6     6        6
#7      7     7        7
#8      8     8        8
#9      9     9        9
#10    10    10       10
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use bquote for this:

```
eval(bquote(
  dat %>% 
    mutate(.(newvar) := .(var))
))
```

you could also update old school in your particular case

```
dat[[newvar]] = dat[[var]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start to write functions with variable names with arguments, you might find `data.table` more convenient than `dplyr`. I recently wrote a [post on the subject](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/). Standard evaluation is easier to handle with `data.table` than `dplyr`, in my opinion.

With `data.table`, you have several ways to use column names as argument

## Using get

You can use `get` that maps a name with a value in a certain scope. Here the scope is your `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
funtest <- function(dat,var,newvar){
  dat[, (newvar) := get(var)]
}
```

`:=` is an update-by-reference operator. If you want to know more about it, `data.table` vignettes are a good place to start. Calling the function:

```r
dt = data.table(iris)

funtest(dt, "Species","x")[]
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species         x
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa    setosa
 ---                                                                      
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica virginica
```

## Using .SD

You can also use `.SD` that means *Subset of Data*. This is more convenient when you have several variables quoted. It avoids the `!!!rlang::sym` necessary for `dplyr`.

You can find yourself making complicated computations with a very concise syntax:

```r
df[, newcolnames := lapply(.SD, mean), by = grouping_var, .SDcols = xvars]
```