# Using dynamic variable in right side of the dplyr formula

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I wish to relevel the Species in `iris` dataset so that the reference level becomes "virginica"

```
want_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = relevel(factor(Species), ref = "virginica")) 
want_iris$Species
...
[141] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
Levels: virginica setosa versicolor
```

However, let's say I wish to dynamically change the variable (Species) and reference level (virginica)

```
var_name <- "Species"
ref_name <- "virginica"

test_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate({{var_name}} := relevel(factor({{var_name}}), ref = {{ref_name}})) 
test_iris$Species

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Species`.
i `Species = relevel(factor("Species"), ref = "virginica")`.
x 'ref' must be an existing level
```

From what I gather from these posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69003844/using-a-composite-to-call-a-variable-dynmically-in-custom-build-function-with-dp)), using dynamic variable on the right side of the dplyr is not straight forward, and I actually asked a similar question on [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214993/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-column-name-as-an-argument), although the question was limited to the column name.

My rough guess is that since `{{}}` unquotes the variable name, I am specifying `ref = virginica` instead of `ref = "virginica"`

How may I approach this problem?

Comment: I think `iris %>% mutate({{var_name}} := relevel(factor(!!sym(var_name)), ref = ref_name))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use `.data`

```
var_name <- "Species"
ref_name <- "virginica"
test_iris <- iris %>%
      mutate(!!var_name := relevel(factor(.data[[var_name]]), ref = ref_name))
```

-output

```
> levels(test_iris$Species)
[1] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option using `rlang::quo`:

```
var_name <- quo(Species)
ref_name <- "virginica"

test_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(!!var_name := relevel(factor(!!var_name), ref = ref_name))
```

You can check out how it's evaluated using `rlang::qq_show`:

```
qq_show(mutate(!!var_name := relevel(factor(!!var_name), ref = ref_name)))

# mutate(^Species := relevel(factor(^Species), ref = ref_name))
```